# Move a List of Files Output from Active Direcotry

Tags: powershell, active-directory, move

I'm new to PowerShell and I'm trying to rebuild a lot of 'wheels' at work that out dated, but sadly still needed.

What: We back up all of our BitLocker Recovery Keys to a Text File.  When the machine falls offline and is deleted from AD, we run a report, and among many things, retire that Text File to Back up.  The script we run looks at AD for the PasswordLastSet Variable and outputs it to a CSV file if that password was set more than 90 days ago so I have a list of machines that need to be deleted in an excel sheet.

What I want to do is take that CSV File and use a PowerShell script to search for those computer names, with the ".txt" appended on the end, and move them to the back up folder.  I can get the script to work ONE at a time, but not in a row.  A copy of my script follows with the server name omitted:

```
$ComputerNames = Get-Content "\\SERVER\Software\Bitlocker\OLD BITLOCKER KEYS\Over_90.txt"
$New_path = "\\SERVER\Software\Bitlocker\OLD BITLOCKER KEYS\FY 18\13 - SEP 18"
$ComputerName = $ComputerNames
$ComputerNames = $ComputerNames +".txt"

foreach ($ComputerName in $ComputerNames)
{   cd "\\SERVER\Software\Bitlocker\BITLOCKER KEYS\Windows10"
        move-item $ComputerNames $new_path -Force
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably start with something like this:

```
$ComputerNames = Get-Content "\\SERVER\Software\Bitlocker\OLD BITLOCKER KEYS\Over_90.txt"
$DestinationPath = "\\SERVER\Software\Bitlocker\OLD BITLOCKER KEYS\FY 18\13 - SEP 18"

foreach ($ComputerName in $ComputerNames) {
    $SourceFile = "\\SERVER\Software\Bitlocker\BITLOCKER KEYS\Windows10\$ComputerName.txt"
    if ((Test-Path $SourceFile)) {
        Move-Item -LiteralPath $SourceFile -Destination $DestinationPath -Force
    }
    else {
        Write-Warning "File '$SourceFile' not found."
    }
}
```

You may need to specify `-ErrorAction Continue` on your `Move-Item` line if you keep getting terminating errors.

Comment: Sweet.  I'll give this a try.  What happens when I run it alone is, it works and computername.txt moved.  When I run it as a batch, I get 'computername' not found and it forgets to append or look for the .txt.  I'm having my morning gallon of coffee right now so I'll try this shotly!